# Hyperledger fabric first network not working with kafka and using TLS

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric

I try to run First network sample [Building Your First Network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html) from official docs. I need to run this sample with kafka orderer type.
For this case I edit configtx.yaml file (changed OrdererType to kafka and added Brokers)

```
...

# Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
# Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
OrdererType: kafka

...

 Kafka:
    # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
    # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
    Brokers:
        - kafka:9093

...
```

And added kafka and zookeeper containers to base/docker-compose-base.yaml

```
....

zookeeper:
 image: hyperledger/fabric-zookeeper
 container_name: zookeeper
 ports:
  - 2181:2181
 networks:
  - byfn
kafka:
 image: hyperledger/fabric-kafka
 container_name: kafka
 environment:
  - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
  - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
  - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=test1234
  - KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=test1234
  - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
  - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=test1234
  - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,SSL://kafka:9093
  - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,SSL://kafka:9093
  - KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES=103809024
  - KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES=103809024
  - KAFKA_UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE=false
 volumes:
  - ./sample/server.keystore.jks:/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
  - ./sample/server.truststore.jks:/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
 ports:
  - 9093:9093
  - 9092:9092
 networks:
  - byfn
```

And I also generated crypto data for kafka client and server.

```
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -validity 365 -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storepass test1234 -dname "cn=kafka" -keypass test1234
keytool -keystore client.keystore.jks -alias orderer -validity 365 -genkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storepass test1234 -dname "cn=orderer" -keypass test1234
openssl req -new -x509 -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -days 365 -subj "/CN=FAB5226" -nodes
keytool -keystore server.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert.pem -storepass test1234 -noprompt
keytool -keystore client.truststore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert.pem -storepass test1234 -noprompt
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -certreq -file server-cert-signing-request.pem -storepass test1234
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -in server-cert-signing-request.pem -out server-cert-signed.pem -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:test1234
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias CARoot -import -file ca-cert.pem -storepass test1234 -noprompt
keytool -keystore server.keystore.jks -alias kafka -import -file server-cert-signed.pem -storepass test1234 -noprompt
keytool -keystore client.keystore.jks -alias orderer -certreq -file client-cert-signing-request.pem -storepass test1234
openssl x509 -req -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -in client-cert-signing-request.pem -out client-cert-signed.pem -days 365 -CAcreateserial -passin pass:test1234
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.keystore.jks -destkeystore client.keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -storepass test1234 -srcstorepass test1234
openssl pkcs12 -in client.keystore.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out client-key.pem -passin pass:test1234
```

And changed orderer container config in base/docker-compose-base.yaml

```
orderer.example.com:
 container_name: orderer.example.com
 image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
 environment:
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  # enabled TLS
  - ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_PRIVATEKEY_FILE=/var/private/ssl/client-key.pem
  - ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/var/private/ssl/client-cert-signed.pem
  - ORDERER_KAFKA_TLS_ROOTCAS_FILE=/var/private/ssl/ca-cert.pem
  - ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
  - ORDERER_KAFKA_SERVER=kafka
  - ORDERER_KAFKA_BROKERS=[kafka:9093]
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
 working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
 command: orderer
 volumes:
  - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
  - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
  - ../crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
  - ../sample/ca-cert.pem:/var/private/ssl/ca-cert.pem
  - ../sample/client-cert-signed.pem:/var/private/ssl/client-cert-signed.pem
  - ../sample/client-key.pem:/var/private/ssl/client-key.pem
 ports:
  - 7050:7050
```

Then I try to run the sample with following command

```
./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a
```

And get error message when script try to create new channel

> Error: got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- cannot enqueue

[Error message when the script try to create new channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXaR1.png)

Please help my to fix this error.

Comment: Please attach orderer logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed problem. Added sleep 30 before running script.sh in cli container.
File docker-compose-cli.yaml

```
command: /bin/bash -c 'sleep 30; ./scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME} ${DELAY} ${LANG}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
```

Comment: Hey @Egor, I got the similar problems.. I am using CLI other than couchDB to start up the container, however your fix not working for me..May you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861659/hyperledger-fabric-first-network-not-working-by-kafka-and-using-tls